# What Vectorizer should I use when I'm doing clustering of text data?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Im doing clustering of text data with Kmeans in Python's Scikit-Learn.
I have problem with Vectorizing the data because I get very different results when Im using different vectorizers.
I want to do clustering of text data (data are instagram comments about USA politics) and I want to find the key-words for every cluster. But I do not know what vectorizer should I use

For example when I'm using :

```
cv = CountVectorizer(analyzer = 'word', max_features = 8000, preprocessor=None, lowercase=True, tokenizer=None, stop_words = 'english')  

x = cv.fit_transform(x)
#should I scale x value?
#x = scale(x, with_mean=False)
#If I do this I get the graph just one dot and silhouette_score less than 0.01
```

I get that my optimal number of clusters is 2, based on `silhouette_score` that gives me score of 0.87. And my graph looks like this:
[image]

And when Im using:

```
cv = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer = 'word',max_features = 8000, preprocessor=None, lowercase=True, tokenizer=None, stop_words = 'english')

x = cv.fit_transform(x)
```

I get that my optimal number of clusters is 13, based on `silhouette_score` that gives me score of 0.0159. And my graph looks like this:

[image]

This is how I'm doing the clustering:

```
my_list = []
list_of_clusters = []
for i in range(2,15):

    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = i, init = 'k-means++', random_state = 42)
    kmeans.fit(x)
    my_list.append(kmeans.inertia_)

    cluster_labels = kmeans.fit_predict(x)

    silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(x, cluster_labels)
    print(round(silhouette_avg,2))
    list_of_clusters.append(round(silhouette_avg, 1))


plt.plot(range(2,15),my_list)
plt.show()


number_of_clusters = max(list_of_clusters)
number_of_clusters = list_of_clusters.index(number_of_clusters)+2

print('Number of clusters: ', number_of_clusters)
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = number_of_clusters, init = 'k-means++', random_state = 42)
kmeans.fit(x)
```

And this is how I plot the data:

```
# reduce the features to 2D
pca = PCA(n_components=2, random_state=0)
reduced_features = pca.fit_transform(x.toarray())

# reduce the cluster centers to 2D
reduced_cluster_centers = pca.transform(kmeans.cluster_centers_)

plt.scatter(reduced_features[:,0], reduced_features[:,1], c=kmeans.predict(x), s=3)
plt.scatter(reduced_cluster_centers[:, 0], reduced_cluster_centers[:,1], marker='x', s=50, c='r')
plt.show()
```

I think that this is the very big difference, so Im sure that Im doing something wrong, but I do not know what.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The Silhouette score, from sklearn:

> The Silhouette Coefficient is calculated using the mean intra-cluster
>   distance (a) and the mean nearest-cluster distance (b) for each
>   sample. The Silhouette Coefficient for a sample is (b - a) / max(a,
>   b). To clarify, b is the distance between a sample and the nearest
>   cluster that the sample is not a part of. Note that Silhouette
>   Coefficient is only defined if number of labels is 2 <= n_labels <=
>   n_samples - 1.
>
> This function returns the mean Silhouette Coefficient over all
>   samples. To obtain the values for each sample, use silhouette_samples.
>
> The best value is 1 and the worst value is -1. Values near 0 indicate
>   overlapping clusters. Negative values generally indicate that a sample
>   has been assigned to the wrong cluster, as a different cluster is more
>   similar.

Your best value is near 0, which means you don't have a good clustering

A good clustering is a clustering in which:

- the intra-class similarity is high (the documents in your cluster are similar).
- the inter-class similarity is low (the documents from two clusters are not similar).

And of course, the clusters should tell you something interesting. For example one cluster could contains all the words linked to a specific domain. But this is a work that you do after the clusters are done.

Changing the vectorizing means that you are changing the features on which you are doing clustering.

From the python sklearn doc, `CountVectorizer`:

> CountVectorizer implements both tokenization and occurrence counting
>   in a single class

Basically you have the token counts as features.

Instead for `TfidfVectorizer`:

> Convert a collection of raw documents to a matrix of TF-IDF features.

Which means that you are using the `Term Frequency - Inverse Document Frequency` formula as features for your documents, which is calculated as:

> TF(t) = (Number of times term t appears in a document) / (Total
>   number of terms in the document).   IDF(t) = log_e(Total number of
>   documents / Number of documents with term t in it)
>
> TF-IDF = TF(t) * IDF(t)

Comment: I want to do clustering of text data (data are instagram comments about usa politics) and I want to find the key-words for every cluster. So I do not know what vectorizer should I use

Comment: @taga you need to do some feature engineering and try different things. A priori someone cannot say if one feature extraction si better than another. I think that you need to do some feature selection, feature engineering. There are a lot of things that you can try

Comment: Anyway, The TF-IDF is a good way to extract the most significative words in a cluster

Comment: Thanks, I know how to use feature selection when I have a lot of columns and numeric data. But here I have one column with text data, so I do not know how can I do that

Comment: I want to do clustering of text data (data are instagram comments about usa politics) and I want to find the key-words for every cluster. So I do not know what vectorizer should I use, what is your advice?

Is there any analogy what vectorizer should I use when? (when should I use TfidfVectorizer and when CountVectorizer)

Comment: When you do Vectorizing you are de facto obtaining a (new) set of features for every text. You are doing feature engineering. After that you can do (for example) a feature selection. But again, it is not simple, and I cannot assure you that this will lead to a good result. Clustering requires hours of analysis and observations, using different tecniques. There is no easy recipe unfortunately